# CNN - index 6 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 6

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have six classes in total. label 1-6.
I am not sure why I get the following error message:
"index 6 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 6"

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(final, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

print("X:", final.shape)
print("y:", y.shape)

print("Xtrain:", X_train.shape)
print("y_train:", y_train.shape)
print("X_test:", X_test.shape)
print("y_test:", y_test.shape)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

y_train = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(30, 1200, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

----> y_train = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 6

the printing of the shapes above gives the following output, if that helps:

```
X: (1134, 100, 1200)
y: (1134,)
Xtrain: (850, 100, 1200)
y_train: (850,)
X_test: (284, 100, 1200)
y_test: (284,)
```

is the rest of the network correctly defined?

Comment: try this `to_categorical(y_train - 1, num_classes)`

Comment: Seems to be working. However I get also an error at the last cell: "history = model.fit.."        ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_14 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 100, 1200). Not sure why.

Comment: Shouldn't six classes correspond to label 0-5?

Comment: Good hint. I am going to change labels to 0-5 (from 1-6)

Answer (score 0):

you need to examine the values in y. These values should all be in the range from 0 to number of classes-1. For example to determine the number of classes in y use
np.unique

```
y=[0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0,]
unique=np.unique(y)
num_classes=len(unique)
print (unique, 'num_classes= ', num_classes)
```

the result would be

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5] num_classes=  6
```

then if you run

```
y_cat=keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes)
print (y_cat)
```

the result would be

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Note to use keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes) each y value must be
less than num_classes or else it will throw an error. For example change Y to include the value 50

```
y=[0,1,2,3,4,50,4,3,2,1,0,]
unique=np.unique(y)
num_classes=len(unique)
print (unique, 'num_classes= ', num_classes)
```

if you run this the result is

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4 50] num_classes=  6
```

however if you then run

```
y_cat=keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes)
print (y_cat)
```

you get the error

```
IndexError: index 50 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 6
```

Comment: hi guys! Can you help me solve this question. It's very urgent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69439472/timedistributed-layer-using-functional-layer-api-valueerror